# Proper way to set UIScrollView with constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a simple horizontal scroll between two view controllers positioned side by side programmatically using constraints. What I have here appears to work but everything I've read says that I don't need to configure the size of the `contentSize` if the constraints are set correctly--autolayout will do that for me. But when I remove `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 2, height: view.bounds.height)` from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, it doesn't scroll. Where did I go wrong?

```
class ViewController0: UIViewController {


    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentView = UIView()
    let page1 = ViewController1()
    let page2 = ViewController2()


    override func loadView() {

        setView()
        addScrollView()
        fillScrollView()

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 2, height: view.bounds.height)

    }


    func setView() {

        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    }


    func addScrollView() {

        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2).isActive = true

    }


    func fillScrollView() {

        addChildViewController(page1)
        page1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        page1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(page1.view)
        page1.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        page1.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        page1.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        page1.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

        addChildViewController(page2)
        page2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        page2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(page2.view)
        page2.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: page1.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

    }


}
```

Comment: this is wrong "contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true", by setting the contentView trailingAnchor to view trailingAnchor, you are setting the contentView width same as view width. Also also all layout constraints for contentView should we created with respect to scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
    class ViewController0: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let page1 = ViewController1()
    let page2 = ViewController1()

    override func loadView() {
        setView()
        addScrollView()
        setupPage()
    }

    func setView() {

        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    }

    func addScrollView() {

        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func setupPage() {
        page1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(page1.view)
        addChildViewController(page1)
        page1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        page2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(page2.view)
        addChildViewController(page2)
        page2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let views: [String: UIView] = ["view": view, "page1": page1.view, "page2": page2.view]
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[page1(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[page1(==view)][page2(==view)]|", options: [.alignAllTop, .alignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints + horizontalConstraints)
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything that I've read has explicitly stated not to add any views directly to the scroll view except for the content view, which should be a view called `contentView`.

Comment: that not always true, contentView is useful when the layout is complex and  we want modifying the existing layout inside UIScrollView. But in this case the UI is pretty simple, so contentView is not required.